# Displaying data from an XML file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm trying to use JavaScript to display data from an XML file. My data isn't being displayed to the web page and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Any help/advice would be appreciated. My code is displayed below.

NOTE - I have no experience with XML so be aware that I am completely new to it.

```
 <script>
    var xmlData;
    function loadXml () {
        var filename = "CDLibrary.xml";
        var XMLhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        XMLhttp.open("GET", filename, true);
        var ok = true;
        try {
            XMLhttp.send();
        }
        catch(err) {
            ok = false;
            alert ("Database not found");
        }
        if (ok) {
            xmlData = XMLhttp.responseXML;
            displayXml(xmlData);
        }
    }
    function displayXml () {
        var CdElements;
        var CdTitle;
        var count;
        CdElements = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("CD");
        for (count = 0; count < CdElements.length; count=count+1) {
            CdTitle = CdElements[count].getElementsByTagName("title");
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML + CdTitle[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</br>";
        }
    }
 </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p id="output">
        </p>
        <p id="buttons">
            <input type="button" id="btnDisplay" value="Display CDs" onclick="loadXml();">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2

Comment: I tried using this, but just switching the xml file and changing the elements to be gotten didn't work.

Comment: 1==> `onclick="loadXml();"` instead of `onclick="displayXml()"` 2==> add `displayXml(xmlData)` after `xmlData = XMLhttp.responseXML;` and test

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml  maybe in your xml file you have changed the CD value

Comment: Mamdouh thank you,  it nows comes up with an error saying database not found. Can you see any other errors? Or is to do with the database itself?

Comment: <CDLibrary>
<CD>
<title>Adiemus: Songs of Sanctuary</title>
<performer>Karl Jenkins (composer)</performer>
<track>Adiemus</track> <duration>3:48</duration>
<track>Tintinnabulum</track> <duration>10:57</duration>
<track>Cantus Inaequalis</track> <duration>3:13</duration>
<track>Cantus Insolitus</track> <duration>5:35</duration>

<genre>classical</genre>
</CD>  

This is a snippet of the xml file. I changed the values of ARTIST and TITLE in the example to performer and title and it didn't work.

Comment: be sure about CDLibary.xml file path

Comment: i added an image of the file folder to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Import XML Data</title></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p id="output">
            </p>
            <p id="buttons">
                <input type="button" id="btnDisplay" value="Display CDs" onclick="loadXml()">
        </div>
<script>
        var xmlData;
        function loadXml () {
            var filename = "CDLibary.xml";
            var XMLhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            XMLhttp.open("GET", filename, true);
            var ok = true;
            try {
                XMLhttp.send();
            }
            catch(err) {
                ok = false;
                alert ("Database not found");
            }
            if (ok) {
                xmlData = XMLhttp.responseXML;
              displayXml(xmlData);
            }
        }
        function displayXml(xmlDataBase) {
            var CdElements;
            var CdTitle;
            var count;
            CdElements = xmlDataBase.getElementsByTagName("CD");
            for (count = 0; count < CdElements.length; count=count+1) {
                CdTitle = CdElements[count].getElementsByTagName("title");
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML + CdTitle[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</br>";
            }
        }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have the same code but it says database not found. Is it because my script is in the head tags and not the body?

Comment: No try to set `XMLhttp.open("GET", filename, true);` instead of false

Comment: and the file url must be right and in the same domain

Comment: Database is till not found :(

Comment: is your XML file in the same directory of your HTML page?

Comment: The files title is simply CDLibrary and is saved in the same folder as the code file, I realised that library had been spelt wrong, i changed it now the error doesn't come up.

Comment: Do you run your code over `file:///` or `http(s):// `

Comment: file:///, i can already see that this is probably the error. Its dumb because i just copied a template my lecturer made, and it doens't work.

Comment: Ok, you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the var xmlData instead you're using a var xmlDataBase. Replace you code to:

```
CdElements = xmlData.getElementsByTagName("CD");
```

And since you're using a global var xmlData, it's  available inside displayXml function, in this case no need for function displayXml(xmlDataBase) if you use function displayXml() it'll be enough.

Comment: `xmlDataBase` is argument not avariable and this isn't the issue

Comment: I made the change and the data still isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the w3schools link and changing some information and changing the directory I got it working. There must be an error in the template i was following, thank you all for your time and efforts.

```
  <html>
  <style>
  table,th,td {
    border : 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th,td {
    padding: 5px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>


 <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
 <br><br>
 <table id="demo"></table>

  <script>
  function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
   }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", "CDLibrary.xml", true);
   xhttp.send();
    }
   function myFunction(xml) {
   var i;
   var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
   var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
   var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
   for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
   table += "<tr><td>" +
   x[i].getElementsByTagName("performer")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
   "</td><td>" +
   x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
   "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```